# Multiple Inputs for CNN: images and parameters, how to merge

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I use Keras for a CNN and have two types of Inputs: Images of objects, and one or two more parameters describing the object (e.g. weight). How can I train my network with both data sources? Concatenation doesn't seem to work because the inputs have different dimensions. My idea was to concatenate the output of the image analysis and the parameters somehow, before sending it into the dense layers, but I'm not sure how. Or is it possible to merge two classifications in Keras, i.e. classifying the image and the parameter and then merging the classification somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Concatenation layer to merge two inputs. Make sure you're converting multiple inputs into same shape; you can do this by adding additional Dense layer to either of your inputs, so that you can get equal length end layers. Use those same shape outputs in Concatenation layer.

Comment: So if my image input is a 256x256x1 matrix and my second input is a float number, I should concatenate it after the CNN analyzed my image? Or before? I'm not sure how adding a dense layer to my float number will transform it to have shape as the image. I looked for examples, but couldn't find one that fits my problem.

Comment: This depends on at which level in your model architecture you want to concatenate those two inputs! I am assuming that you got Convo, Maxpool, etc layers after your image input and similarly your float number input also got other layers added in!? Can you add in your model architecture?

Comment: I have a small CNN with 3 conv-layers, some maxpool layers, a dropout and two dense layers, the last one with 6 neurons for six classes. And I use Swish-activations. I don't have a layer-setup for my float numbers yet, because I'm not sure how to use a float number in a neural network. I defined it as an auxiliary input, but I'm not sure at which point I should use this input. I can't post the architecture today, but it is similar to the [keras tutorial](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d), obviously adjusted for categorical classification instead of binary.